# Breaking Change in EF Core 3.1 to 5 in stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a piece of code that works perfectly in .NET Core 3.1 (EF Core 3.1) but I am trying to migrate to .NET 5 (EF Core 5) but strangely, I am getting an error when I run it in .NET 5.

Here is the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling AsEnumerable after the FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client side.'

Here is the code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TeacherBookingDTO>> GetAllTeachers(string guid)
{
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<TeacherBookingDTO> teachers = await _context.TeacherBookings
            .FromSqlRaw("EXEC GetTeachersAndBookingsWithEveningId '{0}'", guid).Select(c => new TeacherBookingDTO {
                Id = c.Id,
                FirstName = c.FirstName,
                LastName = c.LastName,
                TotalBookings = c.TotalBookings
            })
            .ToListAsync();
            return teachers;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        return null;
}
```

I've tried to use `AsEnumerable`, but I cannot seem to get it to work. If I remove the attempt to return the DTO, ie the `Select(...)` it works just fine. I could of course do the conversion after getting the list back, but I am at a loss why this is not working. I have searched for breaking changes but cannot see anything that suggests any change from 3.1 to 5 that would cause this. It is listed as a breaking change *in* 3.1, but here is my csproj TargetFramework for the working version:

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

Strangely in EF Core 5, my `TeacherBookings` is being created in the database, but not in EF Core 3.1.

Here is a snippet from the `DbContext`:

```
    public DbSet<YearGroup> YearGroups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<TeacherBooking> TeacherBookings { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<StudentBooking> StudentBookings { get; set; }
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add ToList after stored procedure too

```
   IEnumerable<TeacherBookingDTO> teachers = (
await _context.TeacherBookings
 .FromSqlRaw("EXEC GetTeachersAndBookingsWithEveningId '{0}'", guid).ToListAsync()
)
.Select(c => new TeacherBookingDTO {
                Id = c.Id,
                FirstName = c.FirstName,
                LastName = c.LastName,
                TotalBookings = c.TotalBookings
            })
            .ToList();
```

This way FromSqlRaw works. It always returns IEnumerable. So for example if you need only first record  and your stored procedure will return only this record, in any case you will need code like this. At first you will have to load  data as a list of records  and only after this try to do something with this

```
var teacher = (
await _context.TeacherBookings
 .FromSqlRaw("EXEC GetTeachersAndBookingsWithEveningId '{0}'", guid).ToListAsync()
)
.Select(c => new TeacherBookingDTO {
                Id = c.Id,
                FirstName = c.FirstName,
                LastName = c.LastName,
                TotalBookings = c.TotalBookings
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

For example, ExecuteSqlRaw always returns only one property so it doesn't need to be loaded in a special model at first.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your suggestion and it works, what I don't understand is why the original code doesn't work in EF5. It seems weird doing a ToList on a ToList !!